# How to make bootstrap dropdown be shown over a modal-footer instead of making modal overflow?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a modal to allow users to add alarms, one alarm can have many notifications of different kinds, so I want the user to choose which kind of notification he wants via a dropdown.

You can see a (not 100% working) fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/renatoargh/teX7Y/

I am using Bootstrap version `2.3.2`.

Basicaly what happens is shown in the pictures below:

1- Initial state

[image: initial state]

2- Broken state, with dropdown making modal overflow instead of appearing over it

[image]

I have tried setting a huge value to `z-index` of `ul#dropdown-menu` but it doesn't seems to work. Also I have tried changing the `display` property without success.

Can someone help me?

**EDIT**
Opening the dropdown upwards (dropup) to the upside is also not an option since the problem occurs (when the screen is resized to desktop size); http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/teX7Y/1/

Comment: Your add notification link doesn't seem to be working in the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I am not sure why it is not working on the fiddle, I am trying to fix it! The same code works locally! :/

Comment: @renatoargh I'm afraid that it's not possible to achieve that as the dropdown is positioned relative to the modal body unless you position that as `fixed` and adjust `top`/`left` properties by JavaScript. However, you can open up the dropdown above the `Add` link as: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/teX7Y/1/

Comment: @HashemQolami thank you for the suggestion, I will try your idea! Opening it upwards also is not a solution since the same problem occurs when the screen is resized!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just add another class to your `modal-body`

```
 <div class="modal-body girlLookAtThatBody">
```

and of course

```
 .girlLookAtThatBody{
    overflow-y:inherit !important;
}
```

So check it:

http://jsfiddle.net/uUvyy/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I ended up having another trouble which was easier to solve. When more content was added to the modal it was not staying whitin the modal. I simply surrounded new content with another `div` at set it's `overflow-y` to `auto`.